# Strictly convex functionss

Tags: partial-differential-equations, convex-analysis

$f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ differentiable and strictly convex. I know it is $u_r < u_l \iff f'(u_r)< f'(u_l)$ but why is also $f'(u_r)< \frac{f(u_l) - f(u_r)}{u_l - u_r} <f'(u_l)$ then?

Comment: Mean-value theorem ...

Answer (score 1):

We know that by Mean Value Theorem,

$$\frac{f(u_l)-f(u_r)}{u_l - u_r} = f'(\eta)$$

for some $\eta \in (u_, u_l)$. Since $f'$ increases, we have

$$f'(u_r) < f'(\eta) < f'(u_l)$$

Comment: Oh thank you! Pretty obvious haha. But you mean $u_l$  instead of $r_l$ right?

Comment: yes, I made a typo.

Comment: Thank you for your help!